# CSS navigation mobile viewing

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

My website is not working correctly in the mobile browsers here is the [link](http://shriramhostel.in)
the navigation panel is not stretching 100% not covering the about us section
when viewing in the browsers please take a look and suggest a solution thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain:

1) You want to avoid hardcoded margins cos you never know what type of screen size the user has. Instead position your nav in the middle with automatic margins, like this:

```
nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
```

2) Your nav now tries to fit its parent div (navbar), but navbar does not have a width set, so the width stays at 900px. But your #maincontain again has a hardcoded width of 1280px. Your images also have a width greater than 900px, this stretches your page to the biggest size but the navigation remains 900px therefore does not stretch.

3.1) Easy solution: set navbar to have: width: 1280px;

3.2) Correct solution: Remove the hardcoded width from your #maincontain, your images and anywhere else that stretches the screen.

3.3) In a long run, you will struggle to make a responsive website like that, I suggest using http://getbootstrap.com/ as a template, as its responsive, or learn how to use media queries to make your site responsive.

If this helped please UP the post and mark it as an answer! Thanks

Comment: sorry but it didn't work any more suggestions will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you please clarify, how exactly you want the navigation to stretch? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: here is the image i am getting when exploring the site from mobile browsers

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06405536295447677143 please take a look

Comment: @user287332 See updated comment, and please up the post, if it helped any how.

Comment: sorry for not explaining the question thoroughly your answer helped me a lot your efforts are deeply appreciated thanks sir.